# One line repeating counter with itertools?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to write an infinte generator using itertools that combines a the `count` and `repeat` iterators, by repeating each number `n` times before incrementing. Is there a more concise way to do it than what I came up with?

```
from itertools import *
def repeating_counter(times):
    c = count()
    while True:
        for x in repeat(next(c), times):
            yield x

>>> rc = repeating_counter(2)
>>> next(rc)
0
>>> next(rc)
0
>>> next(rc)
1
>>> next(rc)
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use integer division!

```
def repeating_counter(times):
    return (x // times for x in count())
```

Comment: The star import was for brevity, thanks for you answer, seems obvious now.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not as elegant as minitech's answer, I think you can simplify your current logic enough to fit the function body in a single line:

```
def repeating_counter(times):
    for x in count(): yield from repeat(x, times)
```

A `for` loop can run indefinitely (just like a `while True` loop) if the iterator it is consuming never ends. And the `yield from` expression introduced in Python 3.3 makes the inner loop of your code unnecessary. If you're stuck using an earlier version of Python, you'll need to bring that loop back, which I think will require using multiple lines for the function.

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
it = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(itertools.count(), itertools.count()))

>>> next(it) #0
>>> next(it) #0
>>> next(it) #1
>>> next(it) #1
>>> next(it) #2
```

If you want k repetitions:

```
it = itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*[itertools.count() for i in range(k)]))
```